How to finetune certain part of params, via Deepspeed + transformers.Trainner
I have to add some LoRA layers by hand(without left) to a pre-trained Multi-modal model, to finetune the model for new data. I want Deepspeed to optimize ONLY the parameters from the LoRA layer rather than all the parameters. Like this
enter image description here
The platform is hugging face's transformers and Deepspeed.
Therefore I decorate the Trainer from HF's transformers, as below:
enter image description here
Unfortunately, it doesn't work, both LoRA and non-LoRa's weights are not changed during training. It seems that the optimizer in Deepspeed is not the same as that from Pytorch.
My question is, are there any ways that allow me to ONLY finetune certain subnet (LoRA) parameters with Deepspeed+Transformer's Trainer?
Please tell me how to use a customed optimizer, telling deepspeed to finetune only part of the parameters I want to train
